# IllegalStateException when Liferay redirects

Tags: amazon-web-services, liferay

When I log out from Liferay I see the following exception - Liferay tries to redirect to a login page from /c/portal/login.
It happens only when Liferay is behind ELB in Amazon. It works fine in non-Amazon environment. In both cases, there is Nginx before Tomcat.

I use old Liferay 6.0.5 with Tomcat 7.0.42.

```
19 Nov 2015 09:11:42,414 ERROR [MonitoringFilter:136] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call reset() after response has been committed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call reset() after response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.reset(ResponseFacade.java:341)
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.reset(ServletResponseWrapper.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteIpFilter$XForwardedResponse.sendRedirect(RemoteIpFilter.java:664)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendRedirect(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:137)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendRedirect(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:137)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.AbsoluteRedirectsResponse.sendRedirect(AbsoluteRedirectsResponse.java:58)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendRedirect(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:137)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendRedirect(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:137)
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:147)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.callParentService(MainServlet.java:508)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:485)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter.processFilter(StripFilter.java:261)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.themepreview.ThemePreviewFilter.processFilter(ThemePreviewFilter.java:88)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.gzip.GZipFilter.processFilter(GZipFilter.java:126)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:182)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.sso.ntlm.NtlmPostFilter.processFilter(NtlmPostFilter.java:81)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.sharepoint.SharepointFilter.processFilter(SharepointFilter.java:179)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.processFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:184)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.threadlocal.ThreadLocalFilter.processFilter(ThreadLocalFilter.java:35)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteIpFilter.doFilter(RemoteIpFilter.java:890)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteIpFilter.doFilter(RemoteIpFilter.java:926)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1747)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1706)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: This is most probably your code that throws illegalStateException not Tomcat. Can you please share your code to investigate further

Comment: There is no my code in this stacktrace. It is just logout from Liferay. There is no Liferay hooks too.